# Queries allow you to specify Params; But how do I pass params?

Tags: hyperledger-composer

The documentation gives these examples of query definitions. My understanding is items starting with `_$` are parameters you can pass to the query.

The only examples I can find of the `Query()` function inside the transaction processors do not provide parameters.

How can I pass params to my query?

Ala `` let result = Query('MyGreatQueryReqParam`, name = "john"); ``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As answered on Rocket Chat ...

The buildQuery and Query() methods are covered with examples at the bottom of this doc: https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/api/runtime-api
But the short answer is:

`return query('Q1', { inputValue: 'blue' })`